# Проверка ввода данных JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

По примеру написал проверку заполнения данных в `<input>`, если все данные введены то `<input>` подсвечивается зеленым цветом, если нет, красным с выводом `tooltip`.
Проблема в следующем: зеленым обводится, а красным нет.
Что я делаю не так?
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем я допустил ошибку?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mymvn/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="/mymvn/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mymvn/css/signin.css"/>


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="/mymvn/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
     <script src="/mymvn/js/respond.min.js"></script>  
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Пожалуйста войдите</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 sr-only">Login</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required autofocus>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Запомнить меня
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Войти</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="/mymvn/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mymvn/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mymvn/js/common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**common.js:**

```
(function() {

    var app = {

        initialize : function () {          
            this.modules();
            this.setUpListeners();
        },

        modules: function () {

        },

        setUpListeners: function () {
            $('form').on('submit',app.submitForm);
            $('form').on('keydown', 'input', app.removeError);
        },

        submitForm: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);

            if  (app.validateForm(form)=== false) return false;
        },

     validateForm: function(form){
        var inputs = form.find('input');
        valid = true;

        inputs.tooltip('destroy');

            $.each(inputs, function(index, val){
                var input = $(val),
                val = input.val(),
                formGroup = input.parents('.form-group'),
                label = formGroup.find('label').text().toLowerCase(),
                textError = 'Введите '+ label;

        if (val.length === 0){
            formGroup.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
            input.tooltip({
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'right',
                title: textError
            }).tooltip('show');
            valid = false;

        }else{
            formGroup.addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');

        }
            });
            return valid;
            },

        removeError: function (){
            $(this).tooltip('destroy').parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }

    }

    app.initialize();

}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я уже правил твой пример, убери уже наконец с полей  опцию required, если ты делаешь свою собственную валидацию.

Поменяй это:

`<input type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required autofocus>`

На это:

`<input type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" autofocus>`

И со вторым полем точно так же.

В примере ниже все работает. проверяй
http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/QNvxYX?editors=1111

Comment: Да спасибо, все рабоает с вашим примером, не внимателен, и только учусь. Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: У тебя хорошее начало в плане представления скриптов и объявление их как объектов с инициализацией. Молодец

Comment: Бабашев Спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets если у тебя все, пометь ответ как решенный, а то он висит

Comment: Извиняюсь, сделано.